# Why is a new row being added to the foreign key table and not updating the associated row for the entity?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I'm probably making a stupid mistake, but I can't figure out why this is happening. I am initially saving personal info, which creates a row in the question table, but when I go to update the questions it creates a new row in the question table and updates the questionId column to the new row added. Code is below.

```
public class PersonalInfo
{
    public virtual int PersonalInfoId { get; set; }

    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public virtual string Gender { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime GenerationDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Question")]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("QuestionId")]
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }

    public PersonalInfo()
    {
        if (Question == null)
            Question = new Question();
    }
}

public class Question
{
    public virtual int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Question1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Question2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Question3 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Question4 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Question5 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Question6 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Question7 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Question8 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Question9 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Question10 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Question11 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Question12 { get; set; }
}
```

And update code...

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Questions(FormCollection form)
    {
        int id = GetCookie();

        //var questions = db.Questions.Find(id);
        var personalInfo = db.PersonalInfoes.Include(i => i.Question).SingleOrDefault(p => p.PersonalInfoId == id);

        personalInfo.Question.Question1 = form["question1"];
        personalInfo.Question.Question2 = form["question2"];
        personalInfo.Question.Question3 = form["question3"];
        personalInfo.Question.Question4 = form["question4"];
        personalInfo.Question.Question5 = form["question5"];
        personalInfo.Question.Question6 = form["question6"];
        personalInfo.Question.Question7 = form["question7"];
        personalInfo.Question.Question8 = form["question8"];
        personalInfo.Question.Question9 = form["question9"];
        personalInfo.Question.Question10 = form["question10"];
        personalInfo.Question.Question11 = form["question11"];
        personalInfo.Question.Question12 = form["question12"];

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("list");   
    }
```

Comment: seems like you are NOT model binding the action method parameter. please include your entire action method in your post.

Comment: I have included the whole action method.

Comment: have you set a breakpoint to see if the form comes in populated?

Comment: The data is being saved fine. It just creates a new row in the question table and doesn't update the previous one created when the personal info was added.

Comment: When you debug the POST action in the controller, what is the value of `personalInfo.Question.QuestionId`?

Comment: It is saying 0, so obviously not grabbing the previously created row.

Comment: @DaveA, I've had that happen to me on more than one occasion while using MVC and EF together. It's my go to reaction now. :-)

Comment: So there's something wrong with my query "var personalInfo = db.PersonalInfoes.Include(i => i.Question).SingleOrDefault(p => p.PersonalInfoId == id);". How would I do this correctly then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try commenting out this code:

```
if (Question == null)
    Question = new Question();
```

---

UPDATE

There may also be an issue with having 2 foreign keys defined

```
[ForeignKey("Question")]
public int QuestionId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("QuestionId")]
public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
```

as indicated by the error including `Questions_QuestionId`

what happens if you reduce it to one entry:

```
[ForeignKey("QuestionId")]
public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
```

Comment: Without that I get this error, "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.PersonalInfoes_dbo.Questions_QuestionId". The conflict occurred in database "", table "dbo.Questions", column 'QuestionId'.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: @stackDat: But you don't get the error in your comment above in the POST action, do you? You get it when you are *"initially saving personal info*", right? Of course, when you remove the `Question = new Question` line (and you MUST do it, it causes problems), you need to create a `personalInfo.Question = new Question()` before you are *"initially saving"* the `personalInfo`.

Comment: No when I save the personal info in another action method it saves fine and creates an associated row in the question table with null values. When I go to update the questions it doesn't pull previously created associated row and creates a new one. I can just do var questions = db.Questions.Find(id); and save the questions then do var personalInfo = db.PersonalInfoes.Find(id); to get the other info, but I thought there was some way to get one combined entity to work with. Maybe I am mistaken.

Comment: @stackDat: It creates a new one instead of pulling the previously created row because you have `Question = new Question()` in the `PersonalInfo` constructor. Remove that.

Comment: Awesome, that was the problem after all. I saw that in an example somewhere. Not sure why one would ever want to do it that way now. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, `personalInfo.Question.QuestionId` being 0 means that EF will look at that Question record and determine that it is actually a new record, and have no link to the previous one. That's why it's recreating the row every single time.

You can do one of two solutions:

1) Put the QuestionId in your Session Cache, then grab it in the controller, use it to grab the question, and do the necessary updates there.

2) Put the QuestionId in your View as a hidden field, and make sure that it gets passed into the controller when you submit the form. From there just grab the question and do the necessary updates. You can even have that field be an optional parameter so that when it's 0 you know that the question needs to be created.

Comment: So I can't grab the personal info and associated question in one query?